# Confusion with multibytecharacter set and `putc`

Tags: ruby

I was trying to understand how the [`ARGF#putc`](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/ARGF#putc-instance_method) works. I was actually doing test with [`multibyte character sets`](http://www.webmetric.org/white_paper/Multi-byte_Character_Sets.pdf)

Here is the sample:

```
$stdout.putc 63 #<~~~ A
#?=> 63
$stdout.putc 191
#?=> 191
$stdout.putc 181
#?=> 181
$stdout.putc 166
#?=> 166
```

Now my question is,except line **A** - why does every statement printing `?`?

My `Ruby` version is:

```
D:\Rubyscript\My ruby learning days>ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24) [i386-mingw32]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the default encoding (or code page on windows) for your console. You can run `chcp` in `cmd.exe` to check.

ASCII characters contains characters or control characters from `\x00` to `\x7F`. The multibyte character sets uses ISO-8859-1 encoding which contains characters in ASCII and `\x80-\xFF`. Well, inferred from your post, the default code page of your console isn't compatible with ISO-8859-1, so the console don't know how to represent those characters from `\x80-\xFF`.

You need to do some encoding conversion before printing it to your console.

```rb
putc 191.chr.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8')

# UTF-8 is the default encoding used in my Linux environment
# you need to replace it with your console's default encoding
```

Comment: Of course this won't help. Windows doesn't use UTF-8 encoding at all. You just copy-paste and ignore the comments. And further more, you may find out that you console's encoding cannot encode 191 in 'ISO-8859-1', on my computer, the console uses GBK and it doesn't have that character.

Comment: It seems you are master on such `character encoding` issue. :) Could you join here - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24194/ruby